# Python: Bitwise-like list operations

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to elementwise & and elementwise | 2 lists of 8 lists of 6 binary digits, and it is working very oddly. c1 and c2 start as tuples of length 8 with elements that are tuples of length 6, and res starts out as a list version of c1.

anding:

```
for x in range(8):
    for y in range(6):
        res[x][y] = (c1[:][x][y])*(c2[:][x][y])
```

oring:

```
for x in range(8):
    for y in range(6):
        res[x][y] = int(c1[:][x][y] or c2[:][x][y])
```

An example:

```
c1:        ((1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0))
c2:        ((1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0))
anding res:[[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
oring res: [[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Other inputs for c1 and can be messed up in much more than the first sublist.

Edit: This has been resolved. It was most likely alias issues in other parts of the code, and I just ended up using list comprehensions.

Comment: Looping by index in Python is just generally a really bad idea. Use [list comprehensions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) to achieve this kind of thing instead.

Comment: Where did you "initialize" res?

Comment: use `&` for ANDing and `|` for ORing.

Comment: For `oring res`, shouldn't the first element be `[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]`?

Comment: There are better ways to write this code, but it doesn't contain any logical errors. When I run it, I get expected results. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @Lattyware Thank you so much. That is so useful I can't even...wow. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not simply trying something like this using list comprehensions:

```
c1 = ((1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
c2 = ((1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0))

print('Bitwise or:  ', [[k | l for k, l in zip(i, j)] for i, j in zip(c1, c2)])
print('Bitwise and: ', [[k & l for k, l in zip(i, j)] for i, j in zip(c1, c2)])
```

Comment: Because I code sporadically as a hobby, and I didn't know about them.

Answer (score 23):

You could just use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
In [7]: import numpy as np
In [8]: c1 = np.array(c1)    
In [9]: c2 = np.array(c2)

In [10]: c1 & c2
In [11]: c1 | c2
```

Comment: What if I've got [c1, c2, c3, ... c10] and I want c1 & c2 & ... & c10?  Is there a shortcut way to do this?

Comment: `np.logical_and.reduce([c1, c2, ..., c10])`

Answer (score 2):

You can always roll your own class:

```
class BitList(list):
    def anditems(self,other):
        return [se & so for se,so in zip(self,other)]

    def oritems(self,other):
        return [se | so for se,so in zip(self,other)]    

    def xoritems(self,other):
        return [se ^ so for se,so in zip(self,other)]    

print BitList([1,1,0,0,1,1]).xoritems([1,1,1,1,1,1])
    # [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
print BitList([1,1,0,0,1,1]).oritems([1,1,1,1,1,1])
    # [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
print BitList([1,1,0,0,1,1]).anditems([1,1,1,1,1,1]) 
    # [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Then just deal with the nested sublists separately:

```
c1=((1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0))
c2=((1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0))


print [BitList(t1).anditems(t2) for t1,t2 in zip(c1,c2)]
print [BitList(t1).oritems(t2) for t1,t2 in zip(c1,c2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

seems OK to me:

```
>>> c1 =  ((1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0))
>>> c2 =  ((1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0))
>>> res = [[None]*6 for _ in range(8)]
>>> for x in range(8):
...     for y in range(6):
...         res[x][y] = c1[x][y] & c2[x][y]
... 
>>> print res
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
>>> for x in range(8):
...     for y in range(6):
...         res[x][y] = c1[x][y] | c2[x][y]
... 
>>> print res
[[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
>>>
```

I used `&` and `|` for the bitwise operators, but it really shouldn't make a difference since you're just using 1s and 0s.  I suspect that you initialized `res = [[None]*6]*8` (or similar) which is causing some of your sublists to be referencing the same list.

Comment: You did the part that requires thought :)

Comment: I don't know that it required much thinking ... Mostly just copy-pasting like a well trained ape.

Comment: That was my thought too, but I inserted [:]s everywhere I could, including places I knew it was superfluosu, and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
def bitwise(a, b, core): 
  return [int(core(pred, true)) for pred, true in zip(pred_list, true_list)]


pred_list = [1, 1, 0, 0]   # prediction
true_list = [1, 0, 1, 0]   # true

print("| true pos")
true_positive = bitwise(pred_list, true_list, lambda pred, true: pred==1 and true==1) 
print(true_positive)
```

This is a piece of my F_Score.