# Fast way to do a boolean check between two lists in list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, list-comprehension

Is anyone aware of a faster way to do this besides just splitting the list up and running in parallel?

I have 2 lists with T/F values.  I am trying to calculate:

```
list3 = [False if l1[i] == False and l2[i] == False else True for i in range(len(l1))]
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16044397/1084416

Comment: zips the best one?

Comment: This question was wrongly closed IMHO: At the very least the linked duplicate questions is wrong since OP isn't using numpy. He should **not** be using numpy unless he changes his entire code to numpy. I made tests specific for OP's question with timing graphs: https://gist.github.com/Mandera/ef115303d5b1823fc7b710148ff8dc42

Comment: I request that this question is reopened as there is no duplicate regarding boolean lists focused on execution time as OP asks for. The accepted answer is also not right as it's actually not worth the time casting lists to arrays.
This question could also be linked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898804/python-list-of-booleans-comparison-gives-strange-results

Comment: @PeterWood Please see my request to reopen this question, I go into more detail in my github gist above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `numpy.logical_or()`:

```
import numpy
list3 = numpy.logical_or(list1, list2)
```

Comment: `[a or b for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]` is actually faster if `list1` and `list2` are lists.

Answer (score 1):

**Without using additional module:**

This will produce same output as yours with less number of comparisons for each iteration(if lists has more `True` values):

`list3 = [l1[i] or l2[i] for i in range(len(l1))]`

**Edit:**

The answer suggested by [Mandera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3936044/mandera) seems faster than the above one [here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5393746/90395252-8aff7300-e094-11ea-9890-17a28d314da8.png).

`list3 = [a or b for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]`

Thanks for suggesting this.

Comment: Surely just `[l1[i] or l2[i] for i in range(len(l1))]` does the same thing?

Comment: Yeah, will update the answer.

Comment: This is faster than OP's original code but not as fast as `[a or b for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]`: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5393746/90395252-8aff7300-e094-11ea-9890-17a28d314da8.png

Comment: Should agree with this. Wondering how zip() made it faster than the previous one.